# How to show images from source stored in database in adf 12c

Tags: oracle12c, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing fusion web app in adf 12c with database 12c.

Here is the code of image showing on .jsf page.

```
<af:image id="i1" source="#{resource['UplDwn_Data:1.png']}"/>
```

Now i want to show images from the source stored in database.
I have done successfully uploading images and saving source value in database, not storing image as BLOB type in database.

I am storing full source value in database e.g. `"#{resource['UplDwn_Data:1.png']}"`

Here is the code of input text field where i am getting data from database.

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.Image.inputValue}" 
  label="Picture DB" rendered="true" simple="true" 
  required="#{bindings.Image.hints.mandatory}" 
  columns="#{bindings.Image.hints.displayWidth}" 
  maximumLength="#{bindings.Image.hints.precision}" 
  shortDesc="#{bindings.Image.hints.tooltip}" id="it66" 
  binding="#{FileManageBean.dbValue}">
 <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Image.validator}"/>
</af:inputText>
```

Here is screen shot of above code after running in browser:
[image: data stored in database]

I want to use this data as image source to show on .jsf page.

If you have any other idea will be really appreciable, but remember i don't want to store image as blob type in database.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the source attribute of an af:image to the value coming from the DB.
Note that the value in the DB should be the full URL (or at least a relative URL) to the image.

Comment: i have tried this option, but image is not showing there. I have checked the image source value through inspect element in browser, the value is rendering there from database properly.